# C++ Destructor: cannot access private member declared in class

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to create a simple program in **C++** that creates lists of movies using **2 classes**: `Movie`, which contains details of one movie, and `Movies`, which contains a name and a *vector of Movie objects*. The whole point is that the user should only interact with the class `Movies`, therefore I have chosen to make all the members (both data and methods) of the `Movie` class private.

I keep getting the following error if I let `Movie::~Movie()` as it is, but if I comment it in both .h and .cpp, it works just fine.

I have explicitly made `Movies` class a **friend** of `Movie` class, so it can access all its members.

[error from Visual Studio Community 2019](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXkXU.png)

Movie.h:

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

class Movie
{
    friend class Movies;
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string rating;
    int watchedCounter;
    int userRating;
    std::string userOpinion;

    // methods also private because the user should only interact with the Movies class, which is a friend of class Movie
    std::string get_name() const;

    Movie(std::string nameVal = "Default Name", std::string ratingVal = "Default Rating", int watchedCounterVal = 0, int userRatingVal = 0, std::string userOpinionVal = "");

    ~Movie();
};
```

Movie.cpp:

```
#include "Movie.h"

// Name getter
std::string Movie::get_name() const
{
    return this->name;
}


///*
// Destructor
Movie::~Movie()
{
    std::cout << "Movie destructor called for: " << this->name << std::endl;
}
//*/


// Constructor
Movie::Movie(std::string nameVal, std::string ratingVal, int watchedCounterVal, int userRatingVal, std::string userOpinionVal) : name{ nameVal }, rating{ ratingVal }, watchedCounter{ watchedCounterVal }, userRating{ userRatingVal }, userOpinion{userOpinionVal}
{
    std::cout << "Movie constructor called for: " << name << std::endl;
}
```

Movies.h:

```
#pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include "Movie.h"

class Movies
{
private:
    std::string listName;
    std::vector<Movie> vectOfMovies;
    static int listNumber;

public:
    Movies(std::string listNameVal = "Default User's Movie List ");
    ~Movies();

    std::string get_listName() const;
    void addMovie(Movie m);
};
```

Movies.cpp:

```
#include<string>
#include "Movies.h"

int Movies::listNumber = 0;

// Constructor
Movies::Movies(std::string listNameVal) : listName{listNameVal}
{
    ++listNumber;
    listName += std::to_string(listNumber);
    std::cout << "MovieS constructor called for: " << listName << std::endl;
}


// Destructor
Movies::~Movies()
{
    std::cout << "MovieS destructor called for: " << listName << std::endl;
}


std::string Movies::get_listName() const
{
    return this->listName;
}


//Add movie to list of movies
void Movies::addMovie(Movie m)
{
    this->vectOfMovies.push_back(m);
}
```

And the main .cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
// #include "Movie.h"
#include "Movies.h"


int main()
{
    Movies moviesObj;

    moviesObj.get_listName();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is the `Movie` destructor `private`?  Almost inclined to close this as a typo.

Comment: How do you expect to use `void addMovie(Movie m);` if you cannot construct a `Movie`?

Comment: Because I'm only supposed to access the members of the ```Movie``` class through the ```Movies``` class. So I considered that I should put everything in the ```Movie``` class on ```private```, and add ```Movies``` class as a ```friend```  of ```Movie``` class.

Comment: @DragoșBocancea The `std::vector<Movie>` tries to call the `private` destructor of `Movie` via the internal `delete []` call. Thus you either can't use `std::vector<Movie>` and need to do all the memory management yourself by hand, or you make `Movie::~Movie()` a `public` function.

Comment: *Because I'm only supposed to access the members of the Movie class through the Movies class* -- When you make a destructor (or constructor) `private`, then no outside class can create or destroy those objects, unless there is some other `public` way to construct or destroy the object.

Comment: @0x5453 I can construct it, the issue is with the destructor, which doesn't actually do anything, but ```cout``` a message with the name of the Movie object

Comment: @DragoșBocancea -- Doesn't matter if the destructor does nothing, or launches spaceships.  If it is `private`, any entity, such as `std::vector` that requires an available destructor, will issue the compiler error.

Comment: @DragoșBocancea Another option is to make `std::vector<Movie>` a `friend` class of `Movie`

Comment: @DragoșBocancea `Movies` can call `addMovie`, since it has access to the `Movie` constructor, but other code cannot.  Which implies that either `Movie::Movie(std::string, std::string, int, int, std::string)` should be `public` *or* `Movies::addMovie(Movie)` should be `private`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That's what I did ^^

Comment: @DragoșBocancea _"but if I comment it in both .h and .cpp, it works just fine."_ That's because the destructor automatically generated by the compiler is `public` by default. _"That's what I did"_ No, you didn't. Read my comment again: _make **`std::vector<Movie>`** a friend class of Movie_

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie *Doesn't matter if the destructor does nothing, or launches spaceships. If it is private, any entity, such as std::vector that requires an available destructor* - does it matter, if I make ```Movies``` a friend of ```Movie```, which can therefore access ALL the private members of the ```Movie``` class?

Comment: @DragoșBocancea I really don't understand why you have a public `addMovie`, but there is no way any client can use it, since `Movie` cannot be constructed due to the constructor being `private`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you can ignore ```addMovie```. It hasn't been used so far.

Comment: The point of my comment is to see how you're going to accomplish the goal of adding a movie, given the constraints that you have stated.  Even you broke away from those constraints with the `addMovie` function, even though you said it isn't being "used so far".  Have you discussed this with your teacher or whomever gave you this assignment?  I bet that if you get the answer to that question, magically the issue of the destructor will come more into light as to how to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `constructor/destructor` is declared as private, then the class cannot be instantiated. If the `destructor` is private, then the object can only be deleted from inside the class as well. Also, it prevents the class from being inherited (or at least, prevent the inherited class from being instantiated/destroyed at all).

**The use of having destructor as private:**

Any time you want some other class to be responsible for the life cycle of your class' objects, or you have reason to prevent the destruction of an object, you can make the destructor private.

For instance, if you're doing some sort of reference counting thing, you can have the object (or manager that has been "friend"ed) responsible for counting the number of references to itself and delete it when the number hits zero. A private dtor would prevent anybody else from deleting it when there were still references to it.

For another instance, what if you have an object that has a manager (or itself) that may destroy it or may decline to destroy it depending on other conditions in the program, such as a database connection being open or a file being written. You could have a "request_delete" method in the class or the manager that will check that condition and it will either delete or decline, and return a status telling you what it did. That's far more flexible that just calling "delete".

So, I suggest that you could declare `~Movie();` as public. Then, the problem will be solved.